# How do I do a LIKE in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, cakephp

db.courses.find({"course_number":"/^AFPRL/"}) returns nothing.

The following is my DB entry. Forgive me as I'm very new to MongoDB. I believe I'm trying to perform the equivalent of a LIKE operation in MySQL?

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("51072be2f046ed1c0e000000"),
  course_number: "AFPRL 100.00",
  room: "HW  215",
}
```

Comment: MongoRegex is your friend: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php

Comment: Beautiful stuff, 1 step closer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression is not a string. It should be

```
db.courses.find({"course_number": /^AFPRL/})
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped out! This works when I input AFPRL, but when I put AFPRL 1, it breaks it.

Comment: Use \s to match whitespace

Comment: How do I do that in c#?